# First-chance exception during loading dll files in VS2010

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I am using MFC in Visual Studio 2010. I am modifying a code done by someone else. VS2010 loads some files, but on loading the last dll file i am getting

First-chance exception: Microsoft C++ exception: at memory location 0x0014faa0..

I am wondering, is there a way to put a breaking point on loading dll files? the exception happens when VS load a 3rd party dll file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be OK if you see first-chance expection according to this blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx

Quoted below:

**Does a first chance exception mean there is a problem in my code?**

`First chance exception messages most often do not mean there is a problem in the code. For applications / components which handle exceptions gracefully, first chance exception messages let the developer know that an exceptional situation was encountered and was handled.`

This post provides relevant information
[How can I set a breakpoint in referenced code in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617659/how-can-i-set-a-breakpoint-in-referenced-code-in-visual-studio)

Comment: thank you for this information, but this exception also happens every time I call the 3rd party dll file to get the information, So I need to get rid of this exception (if possible)

Comment: @rasred2004 You may try to turn on all exception handlers in VS2010, under "Debug-->Exceptions", most of them are initially unchecked, you may find those that related to dll and check them.

Comment: `ras red2004`, there is nothing wrong with the exception ocurring every time you call.  Again, that is probably normal for that DLL.  If the DLL encounters an exception that it does not catch it will be a second-chance exception, not a first-chance exception.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to worry about first-chance exceptions in third-party code, as that may be a normal part of their execution.  If the third-party code does not handle the exception, it will become a second-chance exception, and then you know something is wrong.