# Debug a referenced DLL in a separate solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have a web project, A, that references a DLL, B, that I would like to debug. I have the DLL source code in a separate solution. Is it possible to step into the dll code without adding the dll project to my A solution?

Thanks!

FGA

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is.  You will need to disable Just My Code to enable this scenario though

- Tools -> Options
- Go to the Debugger section
- Uncheck "Enable Just My Code ..."

You may still have to manually load symbols but after that you will be able to step into your other source code.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this similar question: --> [How to debug a referenced dll (having pdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130417/how-to-debug-a-referenced-dll)

Copy the .dll and .pdb files from your other solution into the bin/ folder of the web project that you're trying to debug. When you run it, it should let you step into the referenced code now. I just did this to debug a referenced membership provider and it worked.