# Set breakpoints in compiled dlls - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have a website I am debugging in VS2015 (ASP.NET).

I'm trying to set some breakpoints in some referenced DLL's.

[Another article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130417/how-to-debug-a-referenced-dll?noredirect=1&lq=1) mentioned

```
"If it is a file (dll) reference, you need the debugging symbols (the "pdb" file)
to be in the same folder as the dll. 
Check that your projects are generating debug symbols 
(project properties => Build => Advanced => Output / Debug Info = full); 
and if you have copied the dll, put the pdb with it".
```

However I can't seem to find the advanced build option in my project properties?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used **Web Site,not Web Application**.

Web Site does not have Advanced Option.But in web application you can set Debug info to Full.
[As you can see image in web application project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA7XR.jpg)

Comment: How can I debug an already deployed web application as a web application in visual studio?

Comment: I Hope help you this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx and this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37182/Debug-your-ASP-NET-Application-while-Hosted-on-IIS

Answer (score 0):

have you seen code of compiled library/DLL? then how can you set breakpoints at there. you can only set break point inside your application where processing is doing by your own logic.

you can set debugging true to debug your application, you may also able to debug logic of the DLL which exported using Debug mode. you can not set breakpoints or debug those library which is made using release mode.