# Debugging executable from the solution in VS 2015 with pdb and source code

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a big solution which contains different projects. I have a particular executable which I want to debug and pdb file for it. I have moved this exe with the pdb and the source code into the same directory. But the source code of the executable is related to source code of other projects included in the solution.

How do I include their source code into VS 2015 to see what happens? The problem is that some function in the source of the current exe calls functions from different projects. How can I see the corresponding sequence of performed actions and its debug information?

I tried to go to the **Solution -> Properties -> Common properties -> Debug Source Files** and add directories but it didn't work for me. I also created pdb file for the required project.

Comment: What does "..but it didn't work for me" mean?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @rrirower
it means that I cannot trace function calls and other information throughout the code - only the "main.cpp" file is available for me

Comment: Have you checked _Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols_ to make sure the debugger knows where your symbols are?

Comment: @newt, As your executable  called other project, so my understanding is that other project was added as the dll reference, so if you want to debug projects, you also need to have symbols for the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130417/how-to-debug-a-referenced-dll-having-pdb