# Debugging external DLL in Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin, dll

I was trying to debug an external library. However, I wasn't able to step into the methods of the DLL here's what I have done.

- I created the DLL from the other library project using the debug mode
  and referenced the DLL in the Xamarin project.
- I copied the pdb file from the library and placed it in the android
  project's bin folder
- I unchecked the Enable Just My Code option

please note that due to source control path length issues I can't add the external library project to the Xamarin project's solution but as I understand that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130417/how-to-debug-a-referenced-dll-having-pdb may help!!

Comment: @MilanG I've already tried this but it didn't work