# Is there a way to get under COM interface from Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, com, atl

I am working on video DLL lib. There is the interface of COM frame class. Which is actually an image. While debugging, I want to see what happens to this frame. But only way to do it - to add `SaveToFile` method to code and recompile. Is three some better debugging tactics or tools for debugging COM interfaces?

It is not hard to write some app with *import* possibility that will visualize frame if I only find the way to *export* it from MSVS during debug session.

Comment: Do you have source for the COM class?

Comment: Yes, this class is a part of lib I am working at. So yes I have full access to it's source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug a referenced dll (having pdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130417/how-to-debug-a-referenced-dll-having-pdb)

Comment: I suggest that you could try to use [comraider](https://github.com/dzzie/COMRaider). It could be used to track com interface.